# assign and compare coding style

Tags: c++, c, coding-style

I've been criticized (without real arguments) for using assign and compare like this in my c code:

```
if (!(buffer = malloc(1024))) {
    // handle failure
}
```

instead of:

```
buffer = malloc(1024);
if (!buffer) {
    // handle failure
}
```

To be clear: This is not about malloc() but only about doing assignments within condition statements.

Personally I prefer the prior version from an aesthetic point of view.

Also if I do a `git grep -E "if \(\!\(.* = .*\)\)\) \{"` in order to identify similar constructs in the current Linux kernel source I find a few hundred identical assignments inside if conditions, e.g. in `net/ipv4/ipconfig.c`:

```
if (!(d = kmalloc(sizeof(struct ic_device), GFP_KERNEL))) {
    rtnl_unlock();
    return -ENOMEM;
}
```

Also used frequently in boost:

```
 // boost/lexical_cast/detail/converter_lexical.hpp
 if (!(i_interpreter.operator <<(arg)))
     return false;

 // boost/iostreams/filter/newline.hpp:
 if ((flags_ & f_has_LF) != 0) {
     if ((success = boost::iostreams::put(dest, LF)))
         flags_ &= ~f_has_LF;
 } else if (boost::iostreams::put(dest, CR)) {
     if (!(success = boost::iostreams::put(dest, LF)))
        flags_ |= f_has_LF;
 }
```

So - **apart from your personal opinion** - are there good technical arguments for or against doing an assignment and comparison in one statement?

Comment: I also prefer the first version. At least if the `!` is involved.

Comment: I can see why people would criticise the first version because you're assigning something that will always return true. Effectively it makes the condition redundant.

Comment: As an aside, if your organization can afford to split hairs on something like that, business must be doing very well.

Comment: Pick _one_ language to ask about. In C++ this would be extra specially doubly wrong just for the use of `malloc` alone.

Comment: @Poriferous Why would that always evaluate to true? It should be false on success of malloc? Or did I misunderstand you

Comment: @Poriferous `malloc` may return `NULL` if it fails to allocate memory successfully.

Comment: @Ctx It is non-zero if `malloc` is successful.

Comment: @Poriferous: Could you please provide a link to where the standard defines `malloc` must never fail?

Comment: @i486 No, it's zero if malloc is successful

Comment: I would *personally* not use any of those styles. And unless you work for some company with style guides, this is a very *personal* matter and totally opinion based.

Comment: @Ctx It is zero if out of memory - otherwise is equal to memory block address (non-zero).

Comment: @i486 We are still talking about the if-condition, right? !(buffer = malloc(4096))

Comment: @JoachimPileborg What do you use in this case?

Comment: @Ctx Yes, but the "true" condition is = error.

Comment: @i486 I give up, please read and think again.

Comment: Critique without objective reason is nonsense. It is mostly a matter what you prefer and are used to. In old times, the compiler did not warn about somethin like `if ( p = NULL )`, which was a common typo (forgot the second `=` of a comparsion operator) (also see "yoda conditions") and lead to wrong code. Since quite some years a compiler should warn about this. Your code OTOH cannot even be missinterpreted, so it is acceptable. For something like `if else (...)` the other version is much more confusing.

Comment: @i486: You missed the negation operator! Ctx discusses the _whole_ expression in the condition.

Comment: Do not add unrelated tags. This is C, not C++.

Comment: I don't think it is opinion-based at all. Assignment inside conditions is widely recognized as bad practice by pretty much everyone except a few stray dinosaurs from the 1980s.

Comment: @Lundin: Or by people trusting their compiler to warn about a potential wrong assignment istead of `==`. There are good reasons to use that which enhance code-quality. But I acknowledge some coding standards disallow such constructs.

Comment: @Olaf This is not C++? Curious, however pedantic I ask the compiler to be, it thinks it is: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/20a26499caae0b5e Admittedly, the initial question already contains a statement that OP does C...

Comment: @Olaf Many coding standards (like MISRA) go further and don't only ban assignment inside conditions, but ban using the result of the assignment operator entirely. For sound reasons, reducing the number of side effects in one single expression is always a good idea.

Comment: The first example reads something like "If not the result of assign 1024 bytes of allocated memory to buffer is zero then handle failure". The second example reads "Assign 1024 bytes of allocated memory to buffer.
If buffer is non-zero then handle failure." Which is easier to understand?

Comment: @Deduplicator: On C++ you have to cast `void *`, in C you should not. Not to mention using `malloc` in C++ in bad style anyway.

Comment: @Olaf: So? That's irrelevant for the code in the question, see the coliru-link in my last comment. And yes, malloc in C++ is in most situations bad style, but still C++.

Comment: @Olaf I don't understand why the c++ tag was removed. The question is definitely covering c++ (see the boost examples). `malloc()` was just used as an example. It could be any function that returns a value that has a success/failure meaning.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Omitting the cast will generate an error in C++. In C casting is discouraged. Common to both languages is just you should avoid unnecessary casts, because every cast weakens type-checking even more.

Comment: @Olaf Which cast? There is none. And why should you cast a `void*` to `void*` anyway?

Comment: @Veterinarian: See my comment above. One more is that you do not have a `static_cast` template in C (you have to use that in C++, though). And from the boost example given: Please provide a link to the C standard where it supports this syntax.

Comment: @Deduplicator: "Which cast? There is none" - Exactly! (Where do you read that `buffer` is `void *`? Standard is to use a proper type for a pointer)

Comment: @Olaf: Yes, there is none, because the type is right. And perhaps take a look at the revision-history: All code was both valid C and C++ when I posted that comment. Anyway, you should really look at the coliru-link I posted quite some time ago.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Why would I follow an external link for a very clear problem? Feel free to write code in the common subset of C and C++. I had enough such code to clean up for customers when they used a more strict compiler/tool or noticed they had to re-write most of that crap. More job-options for me (although I prefer to start a fresh project).

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell, the argument against your version tends to be along the lines of "people don't expect to see *operations* in a conditional". Indeed, when looking over C-like code it takes me a little extra mental effort to spot the `socket`, `bind` and `listen` calls when they're stuffed in an `if`, because I'm expecting an `if`'s condition to check things, not do things.

But that's about it.

Comment: No one expects the Spanish Inquisition!

Comment: Well, what about `if(auto p = dynamic_cast<type*>()) { ... }`, `while(std::cin >> temp) { ... }` and the like?

Comment: @Deduplicator: That apparently is C, not C++!

Comment: @Olaf: How on earth is that C?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Sorry, malworded comment: The **question** is about C, the comment C++, of course.

Comment: @Olaf: Look at the revisions...

Comment: @Deduplicator: Which revisions do you mean? The code did not change.

Comment: @Olaf: The question, because as you observed the answer was never edited. Anyway, have you found a way to tag answers?

Comment: I think you mean "operations with side-effects."

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom: Yes, that would be an accurate way to more verbosely say what I said.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It's important to know that operations often/usually don't have side-effects, like for instance an expression like `buffer != NULL` which is a relational operation.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom: I don't think that level of pedantry is particularly important here, nor even useful.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit What I mean is that people *do* expect to see operations in a conditional (like *i* < *100*). If you say "people don't expect to find ice cream in a hamburger" I think that makes sense but if you say "people don't expect to find food in a hamburger" I tend to disagree.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom: Oh I dunno, depends where you buy the hamburger ;)

Answer (score 0):

I honestly don't see a marked difference in readability. I prefer yours, actually.